# Keep Android Spinner from dropping list

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-spinner

I have an Android spinner that I would like to disable when there's less than one item in my list. What I mean by that is I would like the title to show up, but I don't want a list to drop down when I click it.

I've tried isClickable = false, and isEnabled = false like in many of the posts out there, but I still can't get it to work.

I successfully get ride of the spinner dropdown icon, but I can still click the text and get the list.

```
class CustomSpinnerAdapter(private val ctx: Context, val locations: List<Location>) : ArrayAdapter<Location>(ctx, R.layout.list_item_spinner_view) {
    override fun isEmpty() = locations.isEmpty()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val context = parent.context
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        var view = convertView
        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_spinner_view, parent, false)
        view!!.location_spinner_name.text = locations[position].name
        if (count < 2) {
            view.location_spinner.visibility = View.GONE
            view.better_name.isEnabled = false
            view.better_name.isClickable = false
        }

        view.location_spinner_name.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.assets, ctx.getString(R.string.font_bold))
        return view
    }
```

Here is the view for my title

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/better_name">

<TextView
          android:id="@+id/location_spinner_name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true"
          style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"/>

    <com.ge.cbyge.view.TintableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black"
        android:tint="@color/medium_gray"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_home_spinner_dropdown_padding_top"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: was that answer helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be helpful.  It is not a re-write of your app, but maybe an idea that you can integrate:

You could create your own Spinner class like this:

```
class MySpinner extends AppCompatSpinner {


public MySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    if ( getCount() == 0 ) {
        return true; // we do nothing because adapter contents = 0
    }
    else {
        return super.performClick(); // we proceed as normal
    }
}

}
```

Then alter your XML references from "Spinner" to "[yourPackageName].MySpinner"